# Как получить hwnd по имени процесса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, pywin32

Как получить hwnd окна по имени процесса. Вот например я могу получить hwnd по имени окна

```
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Notepad")
```

Можно ли так же легко получить hwnd по имени процесса?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Совсем просто не получится, потому что:

1. Может быть несколько процессов с одним именем (например, можно открыть несколько окон Блокнота).
2. У процесса может быть несколько окон

Поэтому сначала нужно получить список процессов с заданными именем файла (или для простоты первый попавшийся процесс, подходящий по этому условию), потом список окон для данного процесса (процессов).

## 1. Получаем список процессов, у которых имя файла равно notepad.exe

Можно воспользоваться пакетом [**psutil**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil)

```
import psutil

# Список процессов с именем файла notepad.exe:
notepads = [item for item in psutil.process_iter() if item.name() == 'notepad.exe']
print(notepads)  # [<psutil.Process(pid=4416, name='notepad.exe') at 64362512>]

# Просто pid первого попавшегося процесса с именем файла notepad.exe:
pid = next(item for item in psutil.process_iter() if item.name() == 'notepad.exe').pid
# (вызовет исключение StopIteration, если Блокнот не запущен)

print(pid)  # 4416
```

## 2. Получаем список окон процесса с заданным pid

Чтобы получить список окон процесса, можно воспользоваться функцией [**EnumWindows**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx).

Например, нужно получить все окна процесса с ID 4416:

```
import win32gui
import win32process

def enum_window_callback(hwnd, pid):
    tid, current_pid = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd)
    if pid == current_pid and win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        windows.append(hwnd)

# pid = 4416  # pid уже получен на предыдущем этапе
windows = []

win32gui.EnumWindows(enum_window_callback, pid)

# Выводим заголовки всех полученных окон
print([win32gui.GetWindowText(item) for item in windows])
```

Вывод:

```
['Безымянный — Блокнот']
```

Если в Блокноте открыть еще настройку параметров страницы, то список будет такой:

```
['Параметры страницы', 'Безымянный — Блокнот']
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь очередной раз, но вот стоит задача, мне известно только имя процесса, и известно что имя процесса одно например progID1242111.exe. Мне нужно получить hwnd по имени процесса и получить имя окна. Смотреть пид я не могу. Есть на это у вас пример кода?

Comment: @ДмитрийМизантропович, дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!